# Is it safe to install Virtual Box in Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04

Is it safe (for the system) to install Virtual Box in Ubuntu? Are there relevant disadvantages and advantages?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by sage for the system... Are you worried about corrupting your OS install, or that downloading the package will give you viruses, etc...?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's safe. It works great. Very useful to run Windows without having to reboot or deal with Wine, and you can also experiment with other distros of Linux without having to set up dual-booting.

Comment: Thank You for the response back. The details that you have gave me is very useful. Again thanks.